# MySQL procedure for searching a table with multiple parameters in multiple columns

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, where-clause

I am new to MySQL Procedures and I am trying to write a search procedure for a table.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `Search`(
    IN in_locality VARCHAR(200),
    IN in_type VARCHAR(200),
    IN in_city VARCHAR(200)
)
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM property_details MRP INNER JOIN property_image MRPI
    ON MRP.basic_id=MRPI.basic_id 
    WHERE ((in_locality = '') or (MRP.locality = in_locality))
      AND ((in_property_type = '') or (MRP.property_type = in_property_type))
      AND ((in_city = '') or (MRP.city = in_city)) 
    GROUP BY MRP.id;
END
```

Now this procedure is working for:

```
CALL Search('','','','mumbai');
```

but not for:

```
CALL Search('','',''mumbai','pune'');
```

In normal SQL I could use this query for that:

```
SELECT * FROM property_details where city in('mumbai','chennai')
```

But I don't how to do this in a procedure.

Comment: If you want to search for multiple values for cities, this will not work. You have an equality condition. Do you need a procedure for this? Why not just use a query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CALL examples have got 4 arguments, while your CREATE PROCEDURE statement has only got 3.  This is because you are trying to specify multiple cities.  For this you can use the FIND_IN_SET function to specify the input parameters as comma-seperated lists ([MySQL Docs for FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set))

Instead try this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `Search`(
    IN in_locality VARCHAR(255),
    IN in_type VARCHAR(255),
    IN in_city VARCHAR(255)
)
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        *
    FROM property_details MRP INNER JOIN property_image MRPI
    ON MRP.basic_id=MRPI.basic_id 
    WHERE ( in_locality = '' XOR FIND_IN_SET( MRP.locality , in_locality ) )
    AND ( in_property_type = '' XOR FIND_IN_SET( MRP.property_type , in_property_type ) )
    AND ( in_city = '' XOR FIND_IN_SET( MRP.city , in_city ) )
    GROUP BY MRP.id;
END
```

You can then call this using strings with comma-seperated lists in such as the following examples. I also changed them to XOR's because you don't want it searching for an empty string, and changed all 3 searches to be FIND_IN_SET searches.

```
CALL Search('','','','mumbai'); 
CALL Search('','','mumbai,pune');
```